# Why desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04 don't work properly?

Tags: icons

The problem started using 18.04. I may have accidentally changed some settings. All desktop icons, including the one that I have created, and the ones automatically created by applications, changed their look. They are all the same. Setting a custom icon is not possible anymore. Also, they won't launch the same way, permission is needed every time.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, but the problem got even worse. Now .desktop files work even more complicated, no custom icon, and even sqlite3 files look different.

This how it looks on the Desktop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHd3j.png

And in Nautilus (.desktop is the same):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEz8.png

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling nautilus and perform a fresh install of nautilus?

Comment: I tried this:
sudo apt reinstall nautilus;

There was no change.
Then I tried:
sudo apt remove nautilus;
sudo apt autoremove;
sudo apt install nautilus;

No change again, and i restarted.
Now, the nautilus is the same, and I have NOTHING on the Desktop,

Comment: Can you try `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.nautilus`. This will reset the settings and lets see if it helps

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems like new version of nautilus won't support desktop files at all.